# Are there any airport fees to pay?

Tags: fees-and-charges

I'm travelling from Croatia to Japan in September and I'd like to know if there are any fees I have to pay along the way? 
I'm travelling Rijeka-Stuttgart-Frankfurt-Kansai and then Kansai-Haneda-Frankfurt-Hamburg Rijeka on the way back. I don't know if there are some special airport fees to pay that aren't included in the ticket price?

Comment: That would already be included in your ticket. I'm not sure if it's different somewhere but I ve never had to pay any such fee later on

Comment: In Japan and Germany, all the airport fees and taxes are already included in the price of the airline tickets. I've never flown to or from Croatia, so I don't know about that one.

Answer (score 3):

Airport fees are normally included in the price of the ticket. Having to pay them at the airport belongs to those days of carbon paper tickets. Unless Croatia has special rules, a holdover from the 20th century, you shouldn't have to pay anything. I just came back from Tokyo via Haneda and they didn't ask for anything.

Comment: +1 for carbon paper coupons. Memories. There are probably still a few developing countries that collect the tax in cash at the airport.

Comment: The last time I paid this departure tax in cash was in Indonesia, not so long ago, maybe 2 years ago. 150,000 rupiah if memory serves, and I think they even raised it to 165,000 (+10%) before they dropped that. It was immensely inconvenient to remember to keep 150k in cash -- I used to set it aside in an envelope when I landed :-)